# GCP: Is it possible for a Cloud function to trigger when an Alert fires?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am using Google Cloud Monitoring of Google Cloud Platform.

I have created some alert policies for objects that I monitor. However , When there is an alert that fires a, there are some pieces of  information that are not included that I want included into the email. So I am thinking to use a cloud function that will trigger upon one of the policies I have created if that is possible to do in this case .

If it is possible  please provide advice in this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Monitoring supports using Pub/Sub as a notification channel: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pubsub

You should be able to write a Cloud Function that acts as a Pub/Sub trigger to respond to these events: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub