# Triggering a Cloud Function off GCP Error Reporting Webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'm working on connecting Cloud Error Reporting to an on request Cloud Function (to eventually liaise with the JIRA API).

I have been able to successfully receive Monitoring Notification Channels' test notification to the webhook, however events triggering the email notification channel do not also trigger the webhook.

Is there a way to dispatch on error reporting event to a web URL or pubsub job with error_group attached?

Comment: Can you verify which service is your app deployed? How are you passing the errors from your app, to Cloud Error Reporting, and to your notification channel? Please add more details.

Comment: We're using Cloud Functions, which raise errors that are recorded in Stackdriver and create errors in Error Reporting. None of that was set up by us, all of that stuff is the standard. I'm trying to set up a notification channel using Configure Notifications link on the top of the page, then going to Notification Channels and Manage Notification Channels and adding an entry under Webhooks. When I go back to the Notification Channels, my newly created webhook does not show up.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you're having problems with the UI. Have you tried saving the webhook set-up after testing the connection? I can't reproduce the error you are encountering based on your comment.

Also does this help you? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177769/gcp-is-it-possible-for-a-cloud-function-to-trigger-when-an-alert-fires

Comment: I appreciate your response - we saved the webhook after the setup, but it does not appear under notification channels on https://console.cloud.google.com/errors/setup/notifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon checking on a documentation regarding [managing notification channels](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#managing_notification_channels). Webhooks isn't supported by error reporting, as of now you can select 2 types of notification channels: email and mobile.

There's an ongoing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/141897030) for Webhooks to be added in error reporting notification channel, but there's no ETA when this feature be rolled out . Please star and comment if you wanted the feature to be implemented in the future.

Comment: This has now been added!